# Excel VBA edit IP-adresses and store into variables

Tags: excel, vba, variables, ip-address

Store values in varaibles instead of printing it to a cell.
Below code uses IP-address from a cell in one sheet and changes the last octet with +2 then print it in a cell.

I would like to use that IP-address and add +1 and store in one variable lets say called IP-AddressGateway and then +2 (from original IP-address) to another variable called IP-AddressController.

I don´t want to print the values to a cell just keep them in variables.

```
  For Each c In w1.Range("D2", w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
  If IsNumeric(FR) Then
      v = Split(w2.Range("K" & FR).Value, ".")
      v(3) = v(3) + 2
      c.Offset(, 10).Value = Join(v, ".")
  End If
  Next c
```

I need the `For Each` since I have a lot of other code depending of this. The values stored in the variables will then be used in another module of which I use to print to txt.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove this line from the code:

```
  c.Offset(, 10).Value = Join(v, ".")
```

This is what prints them in Excel.
Depending on what exactly do you need, you may add:

`FR = Join(v, ".")` instead of the `c.Offset(,10)...`

Comment: How does this retain the values in an array?

Comment: @CallumDA - depends what exactly the OP wants and how he has declared the `FR`.

Comment: From the code, `FR` can't be an array...? It seems to be checking if the IP address is in colum A and hence isn't really relevant to the problem (should really be excluded for mcv)

Comment: @CallumDA - `FR` can be anything - from a custom class to a Variant variable - in general, my understanding is that the `OP` does not understand where the printing comes from.